# Union type in typescript to solve incompatibly

Tags: javascript, typescript

I create a small example below to address my issue:

```
interface testType {
    id: number
}

let t: testType[] = [{
    id: 1
}]

t = t.map(item => ({
    ...item,
    id: '123'
}))
```

assume that `testType` came from somewhere else which I don't have control. I want to add a new array of object which its `id` type is not `number`. I don't want to make a new variable name but to use the `t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
interface testType {
    id: number
}

type unionIdTestType = Omit<testType, "id"> & {id: string | testType["id"]}

let t: unionIdTestType[] = [{
    id: 1
}]

t = t.map(item => ({
    ...item,
    id: '123'
}))
```

Comment: I think it's a good idea to use indexed type for the id like so `Omit<testType, "id"> & {id: string | testType["id"]}` just in case the external type changes / is not actually a number. Since the question mentions it comes from the outside and cannot be changed

Comment: Nice one, changed the answer

Comment: thanks, interesting I have to omit then add extra props, thanks!

Comment: this is because intersection works recursively. If you do not omit the `id` then you will end up with a type like this `id: number & (string | number)`, which is impossible. Here's an example of an intersection with repeating keys, notice that the key is an intersection too: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+ZAZzAC5M5SQBXAWwCNoBfLJrUSWRFAIUxz0JKZaFGvShMWYAJ4AHFAGFkAXjTIAZMi5YsAGwhhkCUopUZ8EIqTPlkARgA0yYcgBMyBu6A